# Creating a Flat File using SSIS with 2 header and footer lines, multiple body lines per database record

Tags: ssis, etl

I am trying to create an SSIS package that creates a flat file with the following format:

```
* Header line 1
* Header line 2
* Body line 1
* Body line 2
* Body line 3
* Footer line 1
* Footer line 2
```

The header and footer lines I have calculated and stored as variables (H1, H2, F1, and F2). The body lines are derived from a database query. The way the data needs to be formatted, there will be 3 body lines for each record returned by the query, and each of the 3 body lines for a record will have a different format.

I am not very experienced working with SSIS, and am struggling with how to create a file like this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Here is an example of the format. Vertical lines are used as delimiters:

```
header line| with fields|separated by| vertical| lines
another| header line | separated |by vertical| lines| with additional info
record 1 field 1| record 1 field 2|
record 1 field 3| record 1 field 4| record 1 field 5
record 1 field 6| record 1 field 7| record 1 field 8| record 1 field 9
record 2 field 1| record 2 field 2|
record 2 field 3| record 2 field 4| record 2 field 5
record 2 field 6| record 2 field 7| record 2 field 8| record 2 field 9
footer line| with fields|separated by| vertical| lines
another| footer line | separated |by vertical| lines| with additional info
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your expected output?

Comment: The text itself is going to be medical records in HL7 format. Generally speaking, the header and footer lines will have info like date, file name, hospital name.

Comment: For the body, each db record is going to be represented as 3 lines of text.

Comment: Can you share in your question at least one record to understand the format?

Comment: Please share your input and expected output ?